# Android Q saving media files not showing in Gallary

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contentprovider, android-10.0, android-mediascanner

I'm using Samsung a51.
API level 10

I'm saving different type of file in Download folder like - image, video, song, zip

code

```
val filename = "exampleFileName.jpg"

            val now = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000
            val values = ContentValues().apply {
                put(MediaStore.Downloads.DATE_ADDED, now)
                put(MediaStore.Downloads.DATE_MODIFIED, now)
                put(MediaStore.Downloads.DISPLAY_NAME, filename)
                put(MediaStore.Downloads.TITLE, filename.stripExtension())
                put(MediaStore.Downloads.SIZE, contentSize)
                put(MediaStore.Downloads.RELATIVE_PATH, "Download/my-appname")
                put(MediaStore.Downloads.IS_PENDING, 1)
            }

val uri: Uri? = null

waitForExecution(handler) {
   uri = resolver.insert(
    MediaStore.Downloads.getContentUri(volume),
    values
    )
}

val descriptor = resolver.openFileDescriptor(uri!!, "w")
if (descriptor != null) {
  val outputStream = FileOutputStream(descriptor.fileDescriptor)
  val written = writeFile(outputStream)
  if(written){
     values.clear()
     values.put(MediaStore.Downloads.IS_PENDING, 0)
     if(mimeType != null) values.put(MediaStore.Downloads.CONTENT_TYPE, mimeType)
     waitForExecution(handler) { // ui thread
      resolver.update(uri!!, values, null, null)
      // android says that content resolver automatically notify to system don't need to send brodcast.
      val intent = Intent(Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE))
      context.sendBroadcast(intent)
      }
  }else{
     dontThrow { resolver.delete(uri!!, null, null) }
  }
} else {
   v("got null descriptor.")
}
```

Everything is fine **file** written successfully.
file showing in **File Manager**

but the problem is not showing in the gallery.
and in some other mobile also not working

it also shows in **Mx player**

is there any to notify that file is added

or android 10 bug?

Comment: Specify the mime type right away.

Comment: You dont need that scan intent/briadcast.

Comment: not working. when I specify mimeType when insert it return `null` Uri

Comment: That is not normal behaviour.

Comment: is there any other way to save the file in android download folder

Comment: Well it should work on Android Q. I dont understand why it does not work for you. You can always use SAF.

Comment: With which mime type did you try?

Comment: Ehh... Think your image files in Download directory are private for your app. Hence a Gallery app has no access. I'm not shure though.

Comment: ```val ex = filename.extension() // like .jpg .png .mp4 
        val mimeType = if(ex != null) MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(ex)```  image/jpeg,  video/mp4

Comment: so how to public and also video not showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resolved by setting mimeType when inserting

Comment: what mimetype you have used?